# Let Apigee do authentication (oauth) for client

Tags: oauth, jwt, auth0, apigee

I have a service protected with OAuth. For it to use, you first require a token.
I have an app, that has only access to an Apigee proxy. I would like Apigee to do the authentication for the client (app), and setup protection with an API key for the client in Apigee. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you saying you want Apigee to do the OAuth handshake using credentials stored within Apigee to get the OAuth token and pass it to your service, which will then validate the OAuth token?

Comment: The first part: yes, second part not entirely. 

Apigee fetches a token (from Auth0) with m2m interface, and kees this token in memory (refreshing it from time to time). So Apigee can access the backend service.

Then there's a client application, trying to fetch data via Apigee, with an API key. Apigee validates this API key, and if it's all good, makes a call to the backend service with the earlier required token.

Comment: So I don't want to expose anything of the backend service to the client, I want Apigee to take care of that part (with rate limiting etc. etc.)

Comment: OK, so just to be clear, you're taking a secure endpoint requiring an OAuth token, and lowering that security by only requiring an api key?

Comment: For now: yes. We want to lower the threshold for using the API, and want to take benefit of all the stuff that comes with using Apigee.

Comment: Yeah, the outbound OAuth is definitely what you are looking for.  Took me about 30 minutes to adapt the sample project from Apigee to my needs (simulating your needs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is what Apigee refers to as [Last Mile Security](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/security/last-mile-security).  Unfortunately, it's not as simple as adding a policy and configuring it with a token URL, client ID, and secret.  You'll want to make sure you securely store the credentials, cache the token appropriately, and pass the token on to the proxy target.

Fortunately for you, Apigee has a demo project that does what I believe you are trying to do.  Basically, your proxy will be configured with simply the Verify API Key Policy (Do this first as if the api key isn't correct, no need to do all the OAuth handshaking).  Once confirmed, you can use Javascript policies to check the cache for a token, and then call the OAuth token endpoint to get one if there is a cache miss.  I believe it then uses the AssignMessage policy to set the Authorization header to the token.  (Note that the example project does not include the Verify API Key policy, but that should be easy enough to add)

Additionally, the demo project stores the client ID and secret in a js file, which I would not recommend.  Maybe store it in an encrypted KVM entries?

The Outbound OAuth sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/outbound-oauth).

Comment: I actually followed their instructions, changed the api-config.js to my local OAuth, added the Verify API Key policy, changed the target URL to my own API and had it working.  You can even see the caching at work when the subsequent calls skip the OAuth token retrieval.

Comment: I was actually thinking about this, and it would be more work, but might be a good idea to have a set of credential for each of the api-keys you have authorized to call the API.  That way the underlying API would be able to differentiate the different consumers.  Otherwise, you could have 10 consumers through Apigee, and they would all look like one consumer to your backend API.

Comment: Also, accepting the answer allows others who have the same need to quickly find the one that answers your question.  I believe I provided the solution to your question, even confirming that it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to below videos for using oauth authentication in your API proxies:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn94GhcdgHc&list=PLsWqc60hQz4clQ4ykjCu4qyEhdKe11Lvy

Comment: The poster wants to use outbound OAuth, not OAuth to protect his API proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ouath2 - client credential grant Type, that implies that you must add and configure security policies in your proxy, check the following link that explains this flow.

https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/security/oauth/oauth-20-client-credentials-grant-type

Comment: They want the api proxy secured by api ket only, while the backend target requires an oauth access token to be passed in the Auth header.  they do not want Apigee to require the oauth access token.